# TikZ plot too verbose

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, plain-tex

I was wondering if there was a more succinct way to express the following plot (I'm using the plain format):

```
\input tikz
\tikzpicture
  \draw[help lines, ystep=.5] (-.2,-10) grid (12.5,15);
  \draw[->] (0, -10) to (0, 15) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0, 0) to (12.5, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw (1,-.5) node {$1$};
  \draw (2,-.5) node {$2$};
  \draw (3,-.5) node {$3$};
  \draw (4,-.5) node {$4$};
  \draw (5,-.5) node {$5$};
  \draw (6,-.5) node {$6$};
  \draw (7,-.5) node {$7$};
  \draw (8,-.5) node {$8$};
  \draw (9,-.5) node {$9$};
  \draw (10,-.5) node {$10$};
  \draw (11,-.5) node {$11$};
  \draw (12,-.5) node {$12$};

  \draw (-.5,-10) node {$-20$};
  \draw (-.5,-9) node {$-18$};
  \draw (-.5,-8) node {$-16$};
  \draw (-.5,-7) node {$-14$};
  \draw (-.5,-6) node {$-12$};
  \draw (-.5,-5) node {$-10$};
  \draw (-.5,-4) node {$-8$};
  \draw (-.5,-3) node {$-6$};
  \draw (-.5,-2) node {$-4$};
  \draw (-.5,-1) node {$-2$};
  \draw (-.5,0) node {$0$};
  \draw (-.5,1) node {$2$};
  \draw (-.5,2) node {$4$};
  \draw (-.5,3) node {$6$};
  \draw (-.5,4) node {$8$};
  \draw (-.5,5) node {$10$};

  \draw (0,-10) circle (2pt);
  \draw (1,-9) circle (2pt);
  \draw (2,-8) circle (2pt);
  \draw (3,-7) circle (2pt);
  \draw (4,-6) circle (2pt);
  \draw (5,-5) circle (2pt);
  \draw (6,-4) circle (2pt);
  \draw (7,-3) circle (2pt);
  \draw (8,-2) circle (2pt);
  \draw (9,-1) circle (2pt);
  \draw (10,0) circle (2pt);
  \draw (11,1) circle (2pt);
  \draw (12,2) circle (2pt);
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

It comes out so big it doesn't fit on a page.

Comment: @marmot well I suppose I could try and derive a plain version from a LaTeX answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a LaTeX version.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines, ystep=.5] (-.2,-10) grid (12.5,15);
  \draw[->] (0, -10) to (0, 15) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0, 0) to (12.5, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \foreach \X in {0,...,12}
  {\ifnum\X>0
  \node at (\X,-0.5) {$\X$};
  \fi
  \draw (\X,-10+\X) circle (2pt); }
  \foreach \Y in {-20,-18,...,10}
  {\node at (-0.5,\Y/2) {$\Y$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Amazingly the following does run through with `pdftex`

```
\input tikz
\tikzpicture
\draw[help lines, ystep=.5] (-.2,-10) grid (12.5,15);
  \draw[->] (0, -10) to (0, 15) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0, 0) to (12.5, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \foreach \X in {0,...,12}
  {\ifnum\X>0
  \node at (\X,-0.5) {$\X$};
  \fi
  \draw (\X,-10+\X) circle (2pt); }
  \foreach \Y in {-20,-18,...,10}
  {\node at (-0.5,\Y/2) {$\Y$};}
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but for some reason the `\foreach` wasn't working for me earlier – that shortens the code nicely. I wonder if the new `datavisualization`  command could somehow be used here.

Comment: @morbusg Yes, it could. The question is what you want to achieve. If you only want some axis, grid, and plot of that sort you may be better off with pgfplots. However, I have no experience with plain TeX.

Comment: Well the part inside `\begin{tikzpicture} … \end{tikzpicture}` in your first code block uses only TikZ commands so it's not so surprising that it works with plain TeX too (because TikZ has been designed that way), though I guess it's amazing that TikZ has been implemented that way in the first place. :-) I expect most “LaTeX” answers using only TikZ commands can be quite easily converted to run with `pdftex`.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, that's all true, but the above is the second plain TeX document I ever compiled so for *me* it was a miracle that it immediately worked.

Comment: @marmot Ah I know the feeling :) You're right

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but I would like to point out that assuming  `standalone` class in an answer might not be for the best.

Answer (score 4):

So after spending a night reading the manual while in a trial-error-loop, after many solemn utterances to invoke supernatural power to inflict harm or punishment on something, all of which now regretted, I finally – victoriously – formed the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization, datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization[
    school book axes
    , x axis={unit length=5mm}
    , y axis={
      unit length=5mm
      , ticks={step=2}
      , grid
      , scaling = min at 0cm and max at 5cm
    }
    , visualize as line
  ]
  data[format=function] {
    var x : interval [0:12];
    func y = (\value x - 10) * 2;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Boom! Pow! Shazam! Holy function data format, Batman! This is pretty darn nice, it has to be said.

Only trouble I found, is that it does not work with the plain format, forcing the user to descend to a lower plane of enlightenment.